# Cargo: invalid character `.` in crate name

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Assume I want my executable to be named "index.cgi" (or any other name which is not a correct Rust crate name) and to be built with Cargo.
Is there any way in Cargo to specify a name of output executable, or rename an executable in a post-build step?
The documentation of Cargo is very scarce and I haven't found anything there. (A brief look at the sources didn't helped much too.)

Comment: I don't think it is possible now. You can try creating a feature request in [Cargo issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crate name and executable names must both be valid Rust identifiers.

---

You can set the name of an output executable (see 'Configuring a target' in the documentation for Cargo's [manifest format](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target)), but it also has to be a valid identifier.

```
[[bin]]
name = "index.cgi"
path = "src/main.rs"
```